# How can I run createOptimProblem in matlab?

Tags: matlab

My question is a little bit stupid, but still, I would like someone who can help me if he/she face the same problem as me.

I copy the codes directly from MATLAB mathwork:

```
anonrosen = @(x)(100*(x(2) - x(1)^2)^2 + (1-x(1))^2);
opts = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','interior-point');
problem = createOptimProblem('fmincon','x0',randn(2,1),...
    'objective',anonrosen,'lb',[-2;-2],'ub',[2;2],'options',opts);
```

However, it gives the following error message:

> Undefined function 'createOptimProblem' for input arguments of type 'optim.options.Fmincon'.

`createOptimProblem` should be a built-in function, but with the presence of the error message, I wonder if I need to declare sth before using `createOptimProblem`, what should I do?
I am using R2013a version

Comment: Which MATLAB version are you using btw? If you're using R2010a or later, your code should work.

Comment: It works just fine for me (MATLAB R2015a), no error is shown.